# How can you prevent loss of or bad posture during drumming?

Tags: technique, drums

As an IT technician I am well aware of the problems with posture and the injuries as a result of such problems at work... so I was thinking can the same principles be applied to drumming to prevent strain on the back and legs? if so how can this be implemented?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the back problems, the easiest solution is breathing exercises. It has the indirect effect of making you sit straighter that would otherwise make proper breathing harder. It also gives you a better view over your body instead of *burying your head into the snare* which happens naturally as you wear off especially during practice.

I don't know your level but the most common beginner error is the wrong adjustment of the snare drum height and leaving the left hand rest on the knee. The proper way of doing it is to get a comfortable height such that you can perform a rim shot with arm making approx. 5-10 degrees below the exact horizontal posture. That extra angle provides some space for finger playing supported by wrist action if required without raising hand.

For the drum chair, over the years I've come to believe that the crucial part is the blood-flow and torso balance and it doesn't have any *perfect* spot. It differs from individual to individual. But !

If you sit too high then you need to make sure that you use a proper drum stool such that there is no tendency to block the blood flow by the edge of the stool. Also you need to make sure that you are not falling forward. For example, if your are playing the kick heel up, your feet would be busy playing instead of supporting you. For heel-down it limits your foot action as your feet become pivoted at the heel and it is one of the worse things you can do to your muscles.

If you sit low, then you should be more or less sit no lower than the point where your knees point to the toms. It is bad for two main reasons, you need to raise your whole leg up for heel up action and otherwise your lower leg front muscles (don't know their name) start to burn really fast and it becomes similar to the mouse holding hand suffering from RSI. The other problem is simple making crunches everytime you reach for the cymbals or anything that is not within reach immediately.

Comment: When taking piano lessons my teacher had me sit with hips slightly above the knees.  This helps with blood flow and as well as posture.  I'm not a drummer though...

Comment: Thanks for this answer I never knew that how I was playing reflects almost all of the "donts" expressed in this I play heel down and I have a double kick pedal topping 300 bpm in some songs that I play I dare say I should improve my posture this will help me a lot thanks again :)

Comment: @NathanTaylor My pleasure.